# How to get the date of maximum values of rainfall in programming language R

Tags: r, date, max

I have a data frame with an year of daily values of rainfall (complete dates in column 1,months in column 2, rainfall in column 3). I am trying to calculate monthly maximum rainfall and I also would like to know the date when the maximum occurred.

I tried the following code:

```
for (imonth in 1:12) {
    month <- which(data[,2]==imonth)
    monthly_max[imonth] <- max(data[month,3])
    maxi[imonth] <- which.max(data[month,3])
}
tabela <- cbind(monthly_max, maxi)
write.table(tabela, col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

The monthly maximum worked perfectly but the which.max function is not working correctly. Is giving me rows that do not correspond to the maximum values of rainfall. Can anybody tell me why or maybe suggest a better way of doing this?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using the plyr package

```
library(plyr)

# create a dummy data frame
df = data.frame(date     = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T), 
                month    = sample(12, 100, replace = T), 
                rainfall = sample(1000, 100, replace = F));

# use plyr to figure out max rainfall and date for each month
df.max = ddply(df, .(month), summarize, 
            max.rain      = max(rainfall),
            date.max.rain = date[which.max(rainfall)])
```

Let me know if this works.

EDIT. If there are multiple dates with max rainfall, the code needs to be modified slightly

```
# find max rainfall for each month
df.max = ddply(df, .(month), transform, max.rain = max(rainfall))

# extract subset such that max.rain = rainfall
df.max = subset(df.max, max.rain == rainfall)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tryed your solution but I get an error message in R saying:  Error in date[which.max(rainfall)] : 
                      object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: It works perfectly for me. What version of R are you using? Do you have plyr installed? What are the column names of your data frame? I think a minor tweak is all that is required.

Comment: I think the issue might be a conflict with the R function date. Try changing the column name date to date1 and run the code. It should work

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I downloaded R (don't know the version) and plyr yesterday. I have change the names of all columns and ended up with this file:                                           date1;month;Q
01-01-2010 00:00;1;15.196
01-01-2010 01:00;1;15.196                                          and used the following code:                                            maxi = ddply(obs, .(month), summarize, 
            max.Q = max(Q),
            date.max.Q = date1[which.max(Q)])                      but I am getting this:     "Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE"             Any idea why?

Comment: It looks like your data frame has only one row? Did you try it with a data frame that has 3 columnns (date1, month, Q) and multiple rows?

Comment: Found the problem :) I had an empty row in the end of my data. Now that I deleted it, it works! Just one more thing: I am only getting one date per month, but sometimes the same value of maximum is repeated in different days of the same month. Is there a way to get all the dates when the maximum occurs instead of just the first?

Answer (score 0):

The ***index*** function works well here:

```
library(zoo)
data(AirPassengers)
APZ = zoo(AirPassengers)
ndx = which.max(APZ)

dmax = index(APZ[ndx])
# returns '1960.5' which is Jul 1960 once you know the series freq

frequency(APZ)
# returns 12
```

I have assumed that you are working with a timeseries object; for those (objects created using eg, *ts*, *zooreg*, *xts*) the dates are actually the value indices. If instead you have a dataframe (ie, so that *date* is a column in the data frame and the *value* is another column) then you can just access the row directly.

***Edit*** in light of OP's comment below. For data stored as a data frame:

Suppose your data looks like this, a data frame, D0:

```
D0[1:10,]
# returns

          Time       Value
1  2011-03-12 10:48:24   -3.077784
2  2011-03-12 10:49:24  -20.145500
3  2011-03-12 10:50:24  -45.047560
4  2011-03-12 10:51:24  -69.949640
5  2011-03-12 10:52:24  -94.571920
6  2011-03-12 10:53:24 -112.199200
7  2011-03-12 10:54:24 -118.914400
8  2011-03-12 10:55:24 -114.997200
9  2011-03-12 10:56:24  -97.369900
10 2011-03-12 10:57:24  -78.063800

ndx = which.max(D0$Value)
dmax = D0[ndx,]         # dmax gives the date corresponding to the max value
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it is not a timeseries object, it is a matrix (date is indeed a column in the data frame and rainfall is another column). How can I access the row of my rainfall maximum directly?

Comment: the which.max was what I initially tried but it doesn't work, I think the "month" constrain in "maxi[imonth] <- which.max(data[month,3])" is not working because instead of giving me the dates of the monthly maximums it gives me random rows in the month of January...